# Moment of Inertia for objects moving in a circle?

Tags: rotation, moment-of-inertia

I have been treating objects moving in a circle as a hoop, where $I=MR^2$ and it's been working but I feel like it works for a different reason from what I'm thinking. How do you actually find the moment of inertia of an object moving in a circle of radius $r$?

Comment: Is it an extended object, like a sphere or cube, or a point mass?

Answer (score 1):

The moment of Inertia $I$ is defined such that the rotational energy of the object about it's pivotal axis is $E = I \omega^2$ where $\omega$ is the rotational speed. In the case of a small object moving in a circle of radius $r$, the rotational energy is given by

$$ E = \frac{1}{2} m v^2$$

and using the relation $v = r\omega$, we have:

$$E = \frac{1}{2}(mr^2) \omega^2 = \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2 $$

So therefore the moment of inertia of an object moving in a circle of radius $r$ is simply $I = mr^2$.